# jquery background div slideshow?

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

I've been scouring around for a while looking at different posts on here, but nothing has really been helpful yet except this one I am about to show you from jAndy.

I basically want to be able to put a slideshow in the BACKGROUND of a div.

So far, I have the following code, however, as you can see.... it fadesIn, shows the picture, fadesOut to white, switches the picture, then fades back in to show the NEW picture.....  I simply would like the fades to BLEND together, rather than one fade out and the other fade in.  I know this is rather open ended, but can someone point me in the right direction?

```
 var images = [
       '/slideshow1.jpg',
       '/slideshow2.jpg',
       '/slideshow3.jpg'

   ];
   loop = 0;
   $home = $('#slideme');

   (function fader(){

            $home.fadeOut(1300, function(){
            $home.css('background', 'url(' + images[loop] + ') top center no-repeat');
            $home.fadeIn(1300, function(){
                 setTimeout(fader, 9000);
            });
        });

        if(loop < images.length -1) 
           loop++;
        else loop = 0;                
    })();
```

I sincerely appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/eposar/4/edit)*

You cannot X-fade 2 background images simultaneously cause an element supports only one BG-image. At least not overlapping background images. (correct me if I'm wrong) 
**Instead** you could read your URLs, create real images, and append them to the desired element:

```
var images = [
   '/slideshow1.jpg',
   '/slideshow2.jpg',
   '/slideshow3.jpg'
]; 

var imagesN = images.length;
var $slideme = $('#slideme');

for(i=0;i<imagesN;i++){
  $('<img>',{ src : images[i] }).appendTo( $slideme );
}
```

// NOW YOU IMAGES ARE APPENDED, don't forget to CSS them : `position:absolute;` to get one-over-the-other.

Than you can use my jQuery plugin to fade-loop your images.
The plugin allows you to **pause on hover** and also **click on the image to advance**!

```
/* FadeMe 'FPS'
// jQuery plugin
// Author: Roko C. Buljan (2012)
// www.roxon.in */
(function($){
    $.fn.fademe = function(F,P,S){
        F=F||700;  //  Fade time (default)
        P=P||3000; //  Pause time (default)
        S=S-1||0;  //  Start from 1st image (default)
        var e=this.children(),T;
        function a(){ e.eq(S=++S%e.length).fadeTo(F,1).siblings(e).stop(1).fadeTo(F,0); }
        e.on('mouseenter mouseleave click',function(e){
            var m=e.type==='mouseenter'?clearTimeout(T):(e.type==='click'?a():aa());    
        }).eq(S).show().siblings(e).hide();
        function aa(){T=setTimeout(function(){a();aa();},F+P);}aa();
    };
})(jQuery);


$slideme.fademe(); // initiate plugin on your element
```

By remembering the 'FPS' like: *"Frame-Per-Second"* :) you can easily modify/override the plugin defaults:

```
$slideme.fademe(1300, 9000, 1);
```

that will result in 1300ms Fade; 9000 Pause;  Start from '1st' image (default).
To skip some defaults to reach a property you can do:

```
$slideme.fademe(0, 0, 2);
```

that will be translated in : default Fade (700); default Pause (3000) ; but start from 2nd image.

---

**EDIT** if you want rather to use background images do like:

#### *[jsBin demo 2](http://jsbin.com/eposar/8/edit)*

Comment: LOVE the thought process.  The only issue is that you are appending IMAGES, not BACKGROUND images.  They must be background images because they are going to be very large and used in the background of a full width header div.   If they are images that are 1800px wide, then that will cause sidescrolling.  I am thinking though by your example, I can create x divs and set each div to have that BG image, then use your code accordingly. Thoughts?

Comment: Simple: instead of creating `<img>` create new `<div>`s and add `images[i]` URL from the `for` loop as a background image like: `background: 'url('+images[i]+') no-repeat center center', backgroundSize: 'cover'` http://jsbin.com/eposar/8/edit

Comment: Beaautiful! That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!